# Laravel Carbon Date add 7 minutes

Tags: laravel, date-formatting, php-carbon

My request returns a date string

```
"07/13/2020 8:00 AM - 07/17/2020 5:00 PM"
```

Then I explode it

```
$datetimes = explode(' - ', $request->datetimes);
```

Then I get when I DD

```
"07/13/2020 8:00 AM"
```

When I use carbon to format the string

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($datetimes[0])->format('d M, H:mA')
```

It returns

```
"13 Jul, 08:07AM"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried using Carbon::createFromFormat(''m/d/Y g:i A", $datetimes[0])?

Comment: What is the expected output ? same as this *07/13/2020 8:07 AM*

Answer (score 0):

Because it's converting the date from the american format MM/DD/YYYY instead of the common DD/MM/YYYY

That why when handeling date formats, it's safer to use the mysql date format YYYY/MM/DD

it's how strtotime in php works, if the day is a valid month, it will use the MM/DD/YYYY format.

one easy trick is to replace the `/` with `-` to force it.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse(str_replace('/', '-', $datetimes[0]))
```

Comment: Hey thanks! When I run: dd(\Carbon\Carbon::parse(str_replace('/', '-', $datetimes[0]))->format('d M, H:m A')); It returns: Could not parse '07-13-2020 8:00 AM': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (07-13-2020 8:00 AM) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character

Answer (score 0):

I was using "m" for month instead of "i" for minutes...

Comment: Haha. Gotta love those ones.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give this a try

```
Route::get('convert',function(){
    $myString = "07/13/2020 8:00 AM - 07/17/2020 5:00 PM";
    $dateTimes = explode(' - ', $myString);
    $paseDateTime = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:iA',$dateTimes[0])->addMinutes(7)->format('m/d/Y g:iA');
    return $paseDateTime;
});
```

Output

```
07/13/2020 8:07AM
```